# Bootstrap - Make cards horizontally scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a card carousel but I'm having trouble maintaining the content readable. Here is my current code :

```css
.news-article {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.725rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.19;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333333;
}

.news-source{
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.675rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.19;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333333;
}

.white-background{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-top: none !important;
}

.card-footer{
    background-color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 813px) {
    .white-background{
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border-top: none !important;
    }


    .article{
        width: 400px !important;
        height: 100px !important;
    }

    .news-box{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="pt-3">
        <div class="row news-box no-margin flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <div class="card shadow-sm article col m-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="news-article">
                        The Economic Times
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer white-background">
                    <div class="news-source">
                        The Economic Times
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card shadow-sm article col m-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="news-article">
                        VcCircle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer white-background">
                    <div class="news-source">
                        VcCircle
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

How do i make it scrollable having the same card width?

I tried with `col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6` instead of `col` for each card but it is not working.

I need the width to be equal to that of `col-md-4` in browsers and `PC's` but to have `col-xs-6` in mobiles.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: Hey @Jake, `4.3.1`

Comment: Comment to the author: someone made an edit to your post and changed `<div className="...">` to `<div class="...">`. I tried to reject the change but it already got approved by other SO users.

Comment: It's simply so that it's easier to edit and interact with

Comment: @Jake if you are referring to my comment: see Nithin's comment to the next answer pointing to an "incorrect attribute" where he says his `className` attribute is proper `jsx` notation. You shouldn't change someone's code if you just think it may be easier to edit if you are not sure about the origins of the syntax.

Comment: @SaschaM78, Thats okay `className` and `class` are the same. What Jake did is right, He generalized the code to normal `HTML` and `CSS` from `JSX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnally I'd suggest using an ellipsis by adding this code to `.news-article` and `.news-source`

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

If you'd rather use overflow, simplet set `.news-article` and `.news-source` to `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: auto;` to `article`

**Solution 01** (using ellipsis)

```css
.news-article,
.news-source {

    /* Ellipsis */

    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

.news-article {
    font-size: 0.725rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.19;
}

.news-source {
    font-size: 0.675rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.19;
}

.white-background {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-top: none !important;
}

.card-footer {
    background-color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 813px) {

    .white-background {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border-top: none !important;
    }


    .article {
        width: 400px !important;
        height: 100px !important;
    }

    .news-box {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="pt-3">
            <div class="row news-box no-margin flex-row flex-nowrap">
                <div class="card shadow-sm article col m-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="news-article">
                            The Economic Times
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer white-background">
                        <div class="news-source">
                            The Economic Times
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card shadow-sm article col m-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="news-article">
                            VcCircle
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer white-background">
                        <div class="news-source">
                            VcCircle
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 02** (using overflow)

```css
.news-article,
.news-source {
    
    /* So that the text remains on one line */
    white-space: nowrap;

    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

.news-article {
    font-size: 0.725rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.19;
}

.news-source {
    font-size: 0.675rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.19;
}

.white-background {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-top: none !important;
}

.card-footer {
    background-color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 813px) {

    .white-background {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border-top: none !important;
    }

    .card {
        flex: 0 0 400px !important;
    }

    .news-box {
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="pt-3">
            <div class="row news-box no-margin flex-row flex-nowrap">
                <div class="card shadow-sm article col m-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="news-article">
                            The Economic Times
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer white-background">
                        <div class="news-source">
                            The Economic Times
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card shadow-sm article col m-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="news-article">
                            VcCircle
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer white-background">
                        <div class="news-source">
                            VcCircle
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But adding that would still

Comment: @Nithin please rephrase your comment as this does not make any sense.

Comment: Hey Jake, But adding that would still not make the card's size proper right?! I want to sizes to change depending on the screen size. *

@SaschaM78, Sorry my bad.

Comment: In that case, set the width of 400px on `.card-body` and `.card-footer`. I updated Solution 02.

Comment: Did that, But still the width isn't changing. the `width` of `.card` value in console is set to `400 !important` but still the size isn't changing.

Comment: @Nithin `width` won't have any effect here since its parent is set to `flex-wrap: nowrap;`. Either set `.card`' children `width` to 400px or set `.card` itself to `flex: 0 0 400px;`. Updating solution 02 ASAP.

Comment: @Jake, It works. Marking it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nithin Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class attribute please change `className` to `class`. I hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: This is `jsx` notation. It's from `React`.

Comment: This was badly translated by me when I turned his code into a snippet, that's not the issue here.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui, No still in localhost.

Comment: @Jake, Even i didn't see the edit completely before approving. Now its proper.

Comment: Need more clarifications please share any code snippet/fiddle. Thanks